# Error thrown while executing query : Msg 8618

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using a table three times in a query based on different selection:

```
Select *
from
    (Select * from report where source = 'FA') FA
left join 
    (Select * from report where source = 'PI') PI
          on FA.account = PI.account and FA.Dealer = PI.Dealer
left join  
    (Select * from report where source = 'PIM') PIM
          on FA.account = PIM.account and FA.Dealer = PIM.Dealer
```

As the data is big in volume, I am getting the following error:

> Msg 8618, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
> The query processor could not produce a query plan because a worktable is required, and its minimum row size exceeds the maximum allowable of 8060 bytes. A typical reason why a worktable is required is a GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause in the query. If the query has a GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause, consider reducing the number and/or size of the fields in the clause. Consider using prefix (LEFT()) or hash (CHECKSUM()) of fields for grouping or prefix for ordering. Note however that this will change the behavior of the query.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Do you *really* need `SELECT *` against  every istance of  `report`?

Comment: Not exactly, I need 10 columns from each.

Comment: I would start by minimising the result set to the columns you need. Depending on what you need to do, as well, then conditional aggregation might be what you *really* need. Sample data and expected results will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want without the columns and schemas; but ...

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
        RPT.<
                ... ListOfCommonColumns here
            >
    ,   RFA.<
                ... RFA Columns here
            >   
    ,   RPI.<
                ... RPI Columns here
            >   
    ,   PIM.<
                ... PIM Columns here
            >   

FROM        Report  RPT

LEFT JOIN   Report  RFA ON  RFA.<key>   =   RPT.<key>
                        AND RFA.Source  =   'FA'
LEFT JOIN   Report  RPI ON  RPI.<key>   =   RPT.<key>
                        AND RPI.Source  =   'PI'
LEFT JOIN   Report  PIM ON  PIM.<key>   =   RPT.<key>
                        AND PIM.Source  =   'PI'
                        AND RPT.Account =   PIM.Account 
                        AND RFA.Dealer  =   PIM.Dealer

-- I am not sure, but have the impresion that <key> is a combination of Account and Dealer
```

Answer (score 0):

In my research I found the issue was actually more related to a UNION and a SELECT DISTINCT, example below where TABLE1 and TABLE2 values match but have distinct record sets.

```
WITH A AS (SELECT * FROM JOINTABLE)
SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM TABLE1 
LEFT JOIN JOINTABLE ON
JOINTABLE.COLUMN1 = TABLE1.COLUMN1
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TABLE2
LEFT JOIN JOINTABLE ON
JOINTABLE.COLUMN1 = TABLE2.COLUMN1
)
```

Changing the union to be a UNION ALL and removing the DISTINCT for other methods helped me.

```
WITH A AS (SELECT * FROM JOINTABLE)
SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
LEFT JOIN JOINTABLE ON
JOINTABLE.COLUMN1 = TABLE1.COLUMN1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM TABLE2
LEFT JOIN JOINTABLE ON
JOINTABLE.COLUMN1 = TABLE2.COLUMN1
)
```

Edit: Eventually I had to rewrite the entire query to have better syntax.